# Swift task open file descriptor of pipe

Tags: python, objective-c, swift, macos

I am trying to open a Swift `Pipe` from a python script that is executed via a Swift `Task`

**Swift code**

```
let pipe=Pipe()
let task = Process()
var env=ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
task.launchPath = "/pythonscript.py"

let fh=pipe.fileHandleForWriting
task.arguments = ["\(fh.fileDescriptor)"]
task.launch()
```

**Python**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import os
import sys

fd=int(sys.argv[1])
print(os.fdopen(fd, u'w'))
```

What I get back from the python script is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print(os.fdopen(fd, u'w'))
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Why can't python open the file descriptor I created in Swift?

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't python open the file descriptor I created in Swift?

Short answer (fudging a little): because the file descriptor is a *process local* identifier which is used by the OS to link to the open file information it keeps for process. You cannot copy them between processes.

Long answer:

In macOS/Unix/Linux (*nix) a *file descriptor* is just a process-local value which is used by the OS to link to the appropriate open file information within the OS. Different processes can have exactly the same file descriptor values which identify completely different files. Therefore you cannot simply copy a file descriptor value between processes.

In *nix a child process inherits the open files, and their associated descriptors, from its parent. This is the only way file descriptors get passed between processes. In outline the steps are:

1. The parent process *forks*, creating a clone of itself
2. The clone then closes any files the child should not access (usually all of them except the standard input, output and error files).
3. If the parent has pre-opened files that should be the child's standard input, output or error the clone then reassigns the file descriptors for those files to the standard file descriptors for standard input, output and error.
4. After all this file descriptor work is done the clone then replaces its code with the code the child needs to run - this keeps the open files and file descriptors.
5. The child code now executes unaware of all this setup.

In Swift all the above is handled by `Process`, in `Terminal` it is handled by the shell which uses it to set up file redirection, pipes etc.

To get your pipe to your Python process you can (a) use the `Process` methods to attach it to the spawned processes standard input or output; (b) create a *named pipe*, that is one with a file path, and pass the file path to your python to open; or (c) go low-level and write some interfacing C code which does the `fork`/`dup(2)`/`exec` calls and starts up your python code with the pipe on a known descriptor other than standard input or output.

(a) is easiest! (b) requires you to do some research on named pipes, its not hard but you'll need work with sandboxing if its enabled and create the pipe in a directory both process can access. (c) is best avoided.

Have fun, and if you get stuck ask a new question showing what you've tried, where it goes wrong, etc. and someone will undoubtedly help you along.

HTH